# Error trapping a user input in a function

Tags: python, input

i have been struggling to use this function to trap the errors from a user input.

```
def user_choice():
            choice = 4
            while choice > 3
                    choice = int(input("what list is your card in"))
            return choice
```

any ideas would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean *trap the error*? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Or are you taking about the missing colon? `while choice > 3:`

Comment: no its not the colon, it is just how do i get it to ask the question again if the numbers 1,2,3 aren't inputed?

Comment: See the first link I provided then, simple sol would be `while choice not in range(1,4):`

Comment: def user_choice():
        choice = 4
        while choice not in range(1,4):
                choice = int(input("what list is your card in"))
        return choice

Comment: I did this and it works perfectly thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply by implementing an array with the valid arguments you desire then using the `in` keyword to check if it is there.

```
def user_choice():
        choice = int(input('what list is your card in?: '))
        valid = [1,2,3]
        if choice in valid:
            return choice
        else: 
            print('oops! must be between 1-3 please try again')
            user_choice()
```